# Pseudo Otto Holder proof help.

Tags: real-analysis, holder-inequality

I'm at the first part of a pseudo Otto Holder theorem which claims if $1/p + 1/q = 1$ where $x \in \ell_p$ and $a \in \ell_q$ then $\sum_\limits{i=0}^\infty |a_i x_i| \leq ||a||_q||x||_p$.

For the first part we're allowed to use the fact that for any positive numbers $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$ and any $\lambda \in [0,1]$, we have $\alpha^\lambda \beta^{1-\lambda} \leq \lambda \alpha + (1-\lambda) \beta$. To show that for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$
  \cfrac{|a_i x_i|}{||x||_p||a||_q} \leq \cfrac{1}{p} \left(\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p}\right)+\cfrac{1}{q} \left(\cfrac{|a_i|}{||a||_q}\right)
$$

Let $1/p = \lambda \implies 1 - \lambda = 1/q$

$$
  \cfrac{|a_i x_i|}{||x||_p||a||_q} \leq \lambda \left(\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p}\right)+(1-\lambda) \left(\cfrac{|a_i|}{||a||_q}\right)
$$

I can tell that this almost looks like the homework fact we're told to use but I'm not sure how to get some lambda in the powers on the left hand side... Some diction would be nice.

---

Update

$$
\begin{align*}
\cfrac{|a_i x_i|}{||x||_p ||a||_q}
&= \cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p} \cfrac{|a_i|}{||a||_q} \\
&= \left(\left(\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p}\right)^{\lambda}\right)^{1/\lambda}
\left(\left(\cfrac{|a_i|}{||a||_q}\right)^{1-\lambda}\right)^{1/(1-\lambda)}\\
&\leq \lambda \left(\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p}\right)+(1-\lambda)\left(\cfrac{|a_i|}{||a||_q}\right) \\
\text{Set $\lambda = 1/p$ which implies $1 - \lambda = 1/q$}& \\
&= \cfrac{1}{p} \left(\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p}\right)
 + \cfrac{1}{q}\left(\cfrac{|a_i|}{||a||_q}\right) \\
\end{align*} 
$$

Which is what I was after. Pretty easy once you know the trick! Thanks @PatrickR

---

Image of the homework problem.

[image]

Comment: There are a few problems in your update, when you try to apply the inequality.  Instead make use of $\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p}=((\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p})^{1/\lambda})^\lambda$ and same thing for the $a_i$. And then the right hand side of the inequality should still keep the $1/\lambda$ in the exponent.  Then use that $1/\lambda=p$, etc.

Comment: @ParickR. Your comment makes me think there's a mistake in the homework. The question doesn't have an exponent in the answer. I'll add the picture

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be an extra step involved.  For their second bullet you would need $\alpha\beta\le\lambda\alpha+(1-\lambda)\beta$.  This is *not* true in general, but it is true in the case $\alpha,\beta\le 1$.  And that itself follows from the first bullet.

Comment: Details: $\alpha\beta=(\alpha^{1/\lambda})^\lambda (\beta^{1/(1-\lambda)})^{1-\lambda}\le\lambda\alpha^{1/\lambda}+(1-\lambda)\beta^{1/(1-\lambda)}$.  And then use the fact that because $\alpha\le 1$ and $1/\lambda\ge 1$, we have $\alpha^{1/\lambda}\le\alpha$.  And similarly for $\beta$.

Comment: @PatrickR We're close. for $\alpha^{1/\lambda} \leq \alpha$ we need to know that $\alpha \leq 1$ . We have $\alpha = |x_i|/||x||_p$. Couldn't this evaluate to less than one for some $x_i$? certainly this would be true if it were the infinity norm but we're taking the $p$-norm

Comment: That's easy: take just one element in the sum used to define the norm. $||x||_p=(\sum_{n=0}^\infty|x_n|^p)^{1/p}\ge(|x_i|^p)^{1/p}=|x_i|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $||a||_q$ and $||x||_p$ are not zero.
To show $\sum |a_i x_i| \leq ||a||_p||x||_q$, it is equivalent to show
$$\sum(\cfrac{|a_i|}{||a||_q})(\cfrac{|x_i|}{||x||_p}) \le 1\;.$$
So by dividing the two vectors by their norms you can assume without loss of generality that $||a||_q=1$ and $||x||_p=1$, and you have to show $\sum|a_ix_i|\le 1$.

Now to make use of the inequality you want to use, the trick is to rewrite
$$|a_ix_i|=(|a_i|^q)^{1/q}(|x_i|^p)^{1/p}$$
which is of the form $\alpha^\lambda \beta^{1-\lambda}$ with $\lambda=1/q$ and $1-\lambda=1/p$.

The rest should follow easily.

Comment: Sorry, finally had time to come back to this question! Why can we assume that $||a||_q =1$ and $||x||_p=1$?  Are we just saying that we're going to scale $a$ and $x$ so that it's true? Why would rescaling the norms not effect the answer?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Let me edit my answer to contain what I think is the solution. If you could let me know if my proof is correct, we'll be gucci

Comment: Rescaling by the norms makes things easier.  But you can indeed do it without rescaling, like you are trying in your update.  It's just more messy.